# iab_verifier Android cannot be valid

Tags: javascript, node.js, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I am using node.js iab_verifier module to valid android IAP receipt. I get the receipt json and signature in client side.

```
const IABVerifier = require('iab_verifier');

let googleSignature = signtureFromClient;
let googleReceipt = receiptFromClient;

const googleplayVerifier = new IABVerifier(googlePublicKey);

const testiap = () => {
   console.log(googleReceipt);
   let isValid = googleplayVerifier.verifyReceipt(googleReceipt, googleSignature);
   if(isValid) {
      console.log('valid');
   } else {
      console.log('not valid');
   }
}
```

This is the signature.

```
{
    "orderId": "GPA.3356-2312-7091-22296",
    "packageName": "com.sidequest.notification",
    "productId": "test_gem_tier1",
    "purchaseTime": 1536913771825,
    "purchaseState": 0,
    "developerPayload": {
        "developerPayload": "",
        "is_free_trial": false,
        "has_introductory_price_trial": false,
        "is_updated": false
    },
    "purchaseToken": "bfhdplbkhmclhlbjegjimndg.AO-J1OxEGEU74dKpSJNLXDK0Y39FB3aWQmcGNcTKi6TMYKEZZAetHSi-GMV-FTUCrG0hprKmihryGJ7rMazkhL-pSnvVei0JArFe--UrY0gVB4KkKJqmaJyx0aGuXaHWfk9FbKvy0M75"
}
```

I  don't know why always return not valid message.